# How can I do Join two tables and do Pivot dynamically

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I have two tables, A and B

A ( id, name ) 
B ( a_id, key, value )

table with some values

```
**A table**

-----------------------------
   id        |      name
-----------------------------
    1        |      sorabh
    2        |      john
-----------------------------

**B table**

-------------------------------------------------
     a_id    |     key     |     value
-------------------------------------------------
      1      |    looks    |    handsome
      1      |    lazy     |    yes
      1      |    car      |    honda
      2      |    phone    |    948373221
      1      |    email    |    some@ccid.com
-------------------------------------------------
```

Now what i am trying to achieve is a follow, with single query, inner join, cross join, etc.

```
SELECT * FROM A
CROSS JOIN B WHERE A.id=1
```

and result must be something like

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
  id   |   name   |    looks   |   lazy  |    car   |   email
--------------------------------------------------------------------
   1   |  sorabh  |   handsome |   yes   |  honda   | some@ccid.com 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: you need to use pivot

Comment: It is left join. Result would be row wise (columns would be id, name, a_id, key, value). Your output is called as a cross tab, pivot table. How to do that is based on the backend you are using. For example for postgreSQL check tablefunc extension (this type of data is more suited to NoSQL).

Comment: Consider handling display issues in application code

Comment: The problem with this is that your Table B is going to have a dynamic value. Your resultset for proposed query would therefore have to have a column for each distinct "key" row value for each Id. So ID 1 would have a "phone" column but a null value. As your database grows, so will the null values.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the `id` column of `table a` is a `primary key` column and  `table b` has a composite unique key for `a_id`, `key` column-combination or has no duplicates even if there's no such constraint, a correlated subquery may be used as :

```
select a.*,
       ( select value from b where b.a_id = a.id and b.key = 'looks' ) as looks,
       ( select value from b where b.a_id = a.id and b.key = 'lazy' ) as lazy,
       ( select value from b where b.a_id = a.id and b.key = 'car' ) as car,
       ( select value from b where b.a_id = a.id and b.key = 'email' ) as email
  from a
 where a.id = 1;
```

Comment: That is going to exactly worked, but i want to know, here we know what are the key and values, but is that possible in single query where we don't know looks, lazy, car, email, etc, could be anything and could be multiple or single entry related to it, to query in a single statement with sub statement, to add columns based on key ?

Comment: @sorabh86 I understand what you mean, I've never met such a fully dynamical way, and I believe there's no, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use mysql dynamic pivot to make you expect.

Do pivot with condition aggregate function

Prepared your SQL statements and use to execute your SQL `EXECUTE stmt;` dynamically.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when `key`= ''',
      `key`,
      ''' then `value` end) AS ',
      `key`
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM A join B on a.id=b.a_id
WHERE b.a_id = 1;

SET @sql = CONCAT('select a.id,a.name, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM A join B on a.id=b.a_id
                    WHERE b.a_id = 1
                    group by a.name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[sqlfiddle](https://rextester.com/OPPONO4293)

**Result**

```
id  name    looks       laz   car   email
1   sorabh  handsome    yes   honda some@ccid.com
```

Answer (score 2):

use case when with `max()`

```
select a.name,
 max(case when key='looks' then value end)  as  looks, 
 max(case when key='lazy' then value end)  as  yes,  
 max(case when key='car' then value end)  as  car,  
 max(case when key='email' then value end)  as  email,        
tablea a join tableb b on a.id=b.a_id
group by a.name
```

Comment: What if key and value are dynamic, by the way it didn't worked. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
WITH CTE_A AS (
   SELECT
      A.id,
      A.name,
      B.key,
      B.value
   FROM  A
    INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id
)
SELECT *
FROM
   CTE_A
   PIVOT (max(value) FOR key IN (looks, lazy, car,phone,email)) P
;
```

if the key and value are dynamic use the below

```
DECLARE @colsToPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @sqlStmt  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @colsToPivot = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(key) 
                    from B
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @sqlStmt = 'WITH CTE_A AS (
       SELECT
          A.id,
          A.name,
          B.key,
          B.value
       FROM  A
        INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM
       CTE_A
       PIVOT (max(value) FOR key IN (' + @colsToPivot +')) P'

execute(@sqlStmt)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT * FROM B LEFT JOIN A WHERE A.id=B.a_id AND A.id=1
```